# How do I make the returned message a embed? DISCORD.JS

Tags: discord.js

Hey how do I make the returned message an embed?

```
    return message.reply(`**Here is a list of commands:** \n *Type y!catagory for the commands of the catagory!* \n \n **Economy** \n *y!economy* `);
};

exports.help = {
    name: "help",
    aliases: ["h"],
    usage: "help"
}
```

Comment: Did you read the discordjs.guide website documentation?

Comment: What issues are you facing? Have you done some research at all? We also need to know which version of DJS you're using

Comment: I am using djs v12 for my project.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can check [v12 embeds](https://v12.discordjs.guide/popular-topics/embeds.html#embed-preview) guide or [v13 embeds](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/embeds.html#embed-preview) guide which can help you

Also some code example:

```js
const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
.setDescription(your_text)
.setTitle("Test Embed")
.setColor("RANDOM");
message.channel.send(embed)
```

Please note this code is for discord.js v12.x

For v13 you need to use the `embeds` property

```js
const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
.setDescription(your_text)
.setTitle("Test Embed")
.setColor("RANDOM");
message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed] })
```

Comment: How would I make it so when the user does !help it comes up with an embed?